# Hide a subfolder from site URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have my URL address like this `www.example.com/subfolder/index1` and I want to achieve the following result `www.example.com/index1` (see below I only have 2 subfolders, I have to do the same for both).

The folder that I have in my project are the following:

```
index.html (main page)
subfolder1 -> index1.html
subfolder2 -> index2.html
```

I have the following code in my htaccess file so far:

```
index.html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: What other directives do you have? Any other `.htaccess` files? If the above is all you have then you'd get a 500 Internal Server Error (due to a rewrite-loop). "I'm getting a 404 on the main page" - What URL are you requesting? What file are you expecting to be served?

Comment: @MrWhite I have updated my question regarding your reply. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you!

Comment: And the "updated" `.htaccess` file you've posted is in the document root I guess, not inside the `/subfolder1` etc.?

Comment: Exactly, it's the code I have right now that's working (I wanted to remove the .html at the end of the file)

Comment: Is `/index.html` (in the document root the only file you are serving outside of these subfolders? What about requests for static resources, eg. images, CSS, JS, how are you requesting these? What URLs are you using? Do these include the "hidden" subfolder(s) as well?

Comment: The main page is index.html and 2 other in those 2 subfolders. In each subfolder, as well for the main page I have a folder called assets that includes also folders for images, css and js

Comment: Why do you want to use rewrite?   I'd just move `index1.html` into its parent directory and not have the subfolders at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having two "hidden" subdirectories (`/subfolder1` and `/subfolder2`) you've created an ambiguity. eg. Where should a request for `/foo` be rewritten to? Should it be `/subfolder1/foo.html` or `/subfolder2/foo.html`? The only way to determine this is to first check if the file exists in `/subfolder1`, otherwise rewrite to `/subfolder2`.

You also appear to be using `.html` extensionless URLs. And you appear to be referencing files outside of these two subfolders.

Try something like the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect any direct requests for "/subfolder1" or "/subfolder2" back to the root
# - Except for "assets"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^/]+/assets/
RewriteRule ^(?:subfolder1|subfolder2)(?:$|/(.*)) /$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove "index.html" entirely if requested
RewriteRule (^|.+/)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove ".html" extension if requested directly
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite requests to subfolder1 if ".html" file exists in that subdir
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder1/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ subfolder1/$1.html [L]

# Rewrite requests to subfolder2 if ".html" file exists in that subdir
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder2/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ subfolder2/$1.html [L]

# Otherwise append ".html" if the file exists
# - Only required if you are serving other HTML files outside of the subfolders 
# - (Excluding "/index.html" in the document root)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

A few assumptions:

- your static resources (images, CSS, JS, etc) are requested directly and include `/subfolder1` or `/subfolder2` in the URL. Otherwise it becomes problematic to resolve all ambiguities between `/subfolder1` and `/subfolder2`. However, this does mean the `/subfolder1` (or `/subfolder2`) is not truly "hidden".
- Your extensionless URLs do not contain a dot (which otherwise delimits the file extension).

NB: Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.